# Will the JS runtime use hidden classes for an object literal?

Tags: javascript, optimization, runtime

Thanks to [Mr. Aleph and their wonderful blog](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html), we know that JS runtimes can generate memory-efficient structs for common, consistent classes. For example, with the class:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar: number) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

My understanding is that the runtime may allocate a `struct Foo { double bar; }` when you `new Foo(3.14)`. This is to make access faster and use less memory, but only applies to consistent classes. Typically that means the results of a constructor that keeps returning objects with the same properties.

What happens when you use an object literal instead of a constructor to create the objects? For example:

```
const arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < a_whole_bunch; ++i) {
  arr.push(new Foo(Math.random()));
}

// vs

const arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < a_whole_bunch; ++i) {
  arr.push({bar: Math.random()});
}
```

I'm not sure how to debug the runtime and tell if it generates classes for this. Which runtime isn't especially important, I'm just curious about the difference between the two forms.

Will the runtime ever generate hidden classes for object literals in a hot execution path?

Comment: No, I think, maybe?

Comment: Why does it matter?